# How to check if the code exited out of a loop due to a last command?

Tags: perl, loops

In a loop, I have several conditions and if the condition is not satisfied, I exit out of the loop using [`last`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html) syntax.

```
while (condition) {
    if (possibility 1) {
        ...
        last;
    }

    if (possibility 2) {
        if (possibility 3) {
            ...
            last;
        }
        ...
        last;
    }
}
```

After I come out of the loop, I need to know whether I used last to exit, or the **condition** just did not hold true any more. One way of doing that is to write a if statement that negates all the **possibilities**.

I am looking for some easier/more elegant way to do this.

Is there some Perl variable that stores the information that we exited out of the loop due to last? Or do I need to maintain such a variable myself?

Comment: This is a good sign your code needs to be restructured into subroutines.  Another alternative is to use exceptions rather than `last`.  A more concrete example would allow us to give better advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You pretty much just need to set a flag before you exit

Comment: In other words, you do need to maintain such a variable (flag) yourself, with something like `if(possibility3){flag=3;last;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use the value of variable to check, A refactor like this could work:

```
while (condition) {
    if (possibility 1) {
        ...
        $satisfies_condition = 1;
    }

    if (possibility 2) {
        if (possibility 3) {
            ...
            $satisfies_condition = 3;
        }
        ...
        $satisfies_condition = 2;
    }

    last if $satisfies_condition;
}
```

Based on the value of `$satisifies_condition` you can determine your break point

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought on reading the question was just the opposite of what the previous answers have assumed:  You don't care *which* condition caused the loop to exit early, only whether the loop exited early or not.  Given that you're using a `while` loop, this is done quite easily and naturally, without requiring any extra flag variables, unless one of your branches will change `condition` to make it false before calling `last`:

```
while (condition) {
  # blah, blah, blah
}

if (condition) {
  # condition is still true, loop must have exited early due to "last"
} else {
  # loop exited because condition is no longer true
}
```

If you have early exits which would also make `condition` false, then you do need to add a flag to track whether the last iteration ran all the way through or not:

```
my $iter_finished;
while (condition) {
  $iter_finished = 0;
  if (foo) { last };
  if (bar) { condition = 1; last };
  if (baz) { condition = 0; last };
  $iter_finished = 1;
}

if ($iter_finished) {
  # We exited because condition became false
} else {
  # We exited early due to "last" and we know this regardless of condition's value
}
```